# Are there reports of Luis Suárez biting other players (but not getting caught)?

Tags: football, world-cup

On 24 June 2014, Uruguayan striker Luis Suárez was accused of [biting Italian defender Giorgio Chiellini](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/worldcup/luis-suarez-bite-uruguay-striker-accused-of-biting-giorgio-chiellini-in-latest-controversy-during-world-cup-clash-9560650.html) during the 80th minute of Uraguay's 1-0 group stage win. It wasn't the first time Suárez was accused of biting an opposing player. Suarez was suspended 10 games in 2013 after biting Chelsea defender Branislav Ivanovic. In 2010, while playing for Ajax, Suárez was suspended 7 games for biting PSV's Ottman Bakkal.

These 3 incidents are now well known. But are there lesser known biting incidents in Suárez's past? Are there any quotes by other players suggesting Suárez plays even dirtier than we might imagine?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, he attempted to bite the same player, Giorgio Chiellini, in the Confederation's cup last year, and its attracting a lot of interest in the media. So we can call it a second time lucky for Luis Suarez. See 
[here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/worldcup2014/article-2668987/Luis-Suarez-tried-bite-Giorgio-Chiellini-Confederations-Cup-year-long-wait-finally-got-man.html)

Comment: I'd take anything sourced on Daily Mail with a little bit of caution, since they are certainly inclined towards sensationalism, but [searching a little bit in Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Suarez+Chiellini+Confederation) show that other media are also publishing the same story.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a video clip that seems to show Suárez trying to bite his own teammate and failing.
I've just filed [a question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/in-what-game-did-luis-su%C3%A1rez-seemingly-try-to-bite-his-own-teammate) to find out more about what was going on.

[image: Suárez seems to try to bite his own teammate]

EDIT: After watching this a number of times I think that @Nicholas is right. Suárez is trying to slide on his knees and failing. His mouth is probably open because he's yelling (happily). I'll leave this answer up here for humor value unless a StackExchange expert advises otherwise.

Comment: To say he's trying to bite his own teammate, and captain here, would be completely foolish.

Comment: He's not trying to bite him. But it is funny, and I'm glad you shared it. I think Suarez's biting stems from a deep insecurity he has. Messi, CR7, Drogba, etc. all have it- I'm sure they deal with it in very different ways, mainly resulting in varying success- but Suarez deals with it by biting. Here, with Gerrard celebrating, I can only assume it's that Suarez was screaming and literally slipped too forward.