# In what game did Luis Suárez (seemingly) try to bite his own teammate?

Tags: football, trivia, english-premier-league

Here's a short clip showing Suárez apparently trying to bite his own Liverpool teammate, who was celebrating after a goal. When did this happen? Do we know any additional context that would explain what Suárez was doing and why he was trying to do it?

[image: Suárez seems to try to bite his own teammate]

EDIT: I think @Ben is right. Suárez is trying to slide on his knees and failing. Momentum keeps his upper body moving forward even when his lower body has ground to a halt. His mouth is probably open because he's yelling (happily).

Comment: I don't think Suárez is trying to bite anyone here, I think he's just failing miserably at the sliding celebration maneuver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Steven Gerrard of Liverpool (current Captain of the English national team and Liverpool) celebrating after the second goal of a game vs. Manchester United played on March 16, 2014 (the final score of that games was 3-0 for Liverpool). Gerrard scored on a penalty kick and the GIF above is the celebration after that goal.